# How can I activate a certain choice column based on an item in a certain column in microsoft list

Tags: list, microsoft

I'm creating a list with different types of action.
For example in the column "type" there is *Onboarding, exit, special absence*,...
For each "type" you have a certain actions to do.
I want that when a certain type is added in the list, it automatically generates a certain combination of actions in a choice column.

Can anyone help me how I can realise this?